# is there anyway in Odoo to use it for sell product in multi names but the same in inventory?

Tags: python, design-patterns, odoo

i'am working on a project to autoparts company i'am facing problem in selling a product that can be suitable for KIA and also for Hunday as example 
there is one product in stock but we need to display more than one , every one with different name but with the same QTY (quantity on Hand)
any Idea ???

actually product name is computed field concatenate some fields strings (Item,car,model,year,origin,....)

```
class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
@api.depends('item', 'car', 'model', 'dsc', 'drc', 'year', 'org')
def compute_amount(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.name = " ".join(
            [rec.item and rec.item.name or "", rec.car and rec.car.name or "", rec.model and rec.model.name or "",
             rec.dsc and rec.dsc.name or "", rec.drc and rec.drc.name or "", rec.org and rec.org.name or "",
             rec.year and rec.year.name or ""])
name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=False ,compute=compute_amount,)
```

Comment: You should optimize the process and implement the solution in your program. What is wrong when a product has only one name and is suitable for KIA and Hyundai?
When he is displayed multiple times with the same qty, what happen when customer buy more than one?

Comment: because cashier in pos dunno all product that suitable for other also customer in website actually dunno that the KIA suitable for his hyundai so he well search for KIA

Comment: Okay, than you should optimize the search process, so that the product could be found, when he is searching for KIA or Hyundai. You don't need to display the one product multiple times